# Use SecureString in Membership.ValidateUser(string userName, string password)

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-identity

I got Heap Inspection vulnerability issue in a security report when converting a SecureString password to string and then validate by the MembershipProvider function.  I know that I should use char[] to handle password instead of string.  But how can I pass char[] into the build-in function to avoid the issue?

```
public static string SecureStringToString(SecureString ss)
{
   return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(ss)); //<---Heap Inspection issue
}
...

Membership.ValidateUser(UserName, SecureStringToString(pwd));
```

Comment: _"I know that I should use `char[]` to handle password instead of `string`"_ - according to whom?

Comment: _"Heap Inspection vulnerability issue in a security report"_ - what reporting tool/service are you using? FxCop? SonarQube?

Comment: FWIW, you can see how Microsoft implements `GetSecureStringFromString` and `GetStringFromSecureString` in the reference source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web.extensions/ClientServices/ClientFormsIdentity.cs,69

Comment: char[] is prefered when handling password simply because strings are immutable.  The password will stay on the heap before garbage collection

Comment: @newcoder `Char[]` also exists on the heap and will remain there until collected. (I also assume you mean that you can clear the `Char[]` array but you can't clear a `String`, which is true) - but the problem here is that _eventually_ you'll have to convert that `Char[]` to a `String` in order to do anything useful with it, which defeats the point of using `Char[]` in the first place.

Comment: By using Char[], may be I can compare the password character by character?  The difficulty is that I have to rewrite the ValidateUser() using the existing db.  That is a lot of work as I see the functions under ValidateUser() also pass password using String.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/ADMembershipProvider.cs,3a303b4325b9a88b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how can I pass [a SecureString] into the buil[t]-in function to avoid the issue?

You can't. `Membership.ValidateUser` does not have an overload accepting a SecureString. Why? We don't know. Maybe the ASP.NET Membership framework was not designed for high-security systems where hardening code against heap inspection is a business requirement.

Thus, you only have two options:

1. Use a different (custom-built) user validation method or
2. accept the fact that the password will linger around on the heap for some time.

Comment: I accept this answer because Heinzi clearly state wether a possible approach exists.  JustAnotherDev's answer is helpful too.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommend that you don't use SecureString for any new development. See Remarks here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0

and linked GitHub advice here:

https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

> Don't use SecureString for new code. When porting code to .NET Core, consider that the contents of the array are not encrypted in memory.

To answer your actual question (examples in the link above). You are expected to build the secure string character by character as the credentials are entered. Passing a (complete) char array isn't much different from passing a string.